# Do freelancers have to pay GST if they are providing services out of India?

Tags: taxes, india, gst

If income as an individual freelancer in India is below 20 lakhs and if I am providing services to clients abroad then am I liable to pay any GST in India?

Also what if the person gets orders from clients across the globe via an online portal like freelancer, upwork, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No you are not liable for GST.For more please refer [this source](http://writefreelance.in/gst-freelancers-india/).

Comment: But it's mandatory to get GSTIN number right?

Comment: @newguy, no you need not get GST Number since your turnover is less than 20 Lacs